# Where are files stored when using ownCloud via Docker image?

Tags: docker, owncloud

I've just set up ownCloud on AlmaLinux using a docker image, for use on my local network only.
It's currently set up on my daily driver laptop rather than a dedicated server, so I want to be able to keep track of the amount of available storage. When files are uploaded to ownCloud, where are they stored on the device?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look on [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/), you should be exposing internal storage and config to docker host.